# Automatically turn iPhone sound off after a certain duration

Tags: ios, sound-volume

If I'd like to go to sleep with sound playing on my iPhone, for example, a video playing in the browser, but have it turn off at a certain time during the night, or after a certain duration, how would I accomplish that?

Comment: There's may apps that play sounds and use a times to stop playing after a while.  Have you tried searching the App Store for those?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're referring to an app that acts as a master regulator of this behavior, and turns off all sounds on the phone after a certain time (what would be ideal) or apps with specialized functions, like watching YouTube videos but with sound timeout.  In the former case, I have tried searching for it, yes, and perhaps I don't know the right terms -- results are flooded by functions that aren't what I'm looking for.  In the latter case, I don't know how I would search for this.

Comment: Come to think of it, if worse comes to worse, just turning off the phone could address the issue: https://itstillworks.com/turn-iphone-off-specified-time-19253.html. It would be nice to have an audio specific solution.

Comment: I'm referring to just general apps like White Noise.  They play various sounds and have timers that turn off the sounds after whatever time you set.  These apps don't play Apple Music, Spotify, or Youtube but I can't tell from your question if that's what you want.

Comment: I edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

There is the Screen Time feature in iOS.  Settings -> Screen Time. You could configure a Downtime period and that should shut things off when it engages.

iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch Screen Time
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982

Apple Support Youtube iPhone Screen Time Downtime video:
https://youtu.be/rMfUgqDkZRM

Apple Support Guide - Schedule downtime in Screen Time on Mac
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/schedule-downtime-in-screen-time-mchl69510069/mac

Answer (score 1):

Set a timer in the Clock app, and set “When Timer Ends” to “Stop Playing”.

Unfortunately I don’t see this available as an alarm.